# displaying coordinates sent from my android app on the ushahidi map

Tags: android, plugins, geolocation, maps

My android application fetches coordinates of the users current location and send it to my website which has the Ushahidi platform installed.  I need to display these coordinates on the ushahidi map.  Also the android app fetches coordinates of the new location of the user and sends it to the site, therefore I also need a way to replace the old coordinates of the user with the new ones.

Does Ushahidi have any provisions for this? Is there a clean way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you say display the coordinates on the Ushahidi map. What exactly do you mean? Do you want to display the coordinates on the info window?

You could use the API to update the coordinates. https://wiki.ushahidi.com/display/WIKI/Ushahidi+Public+API

Comment: Alright thank you that works! I am using the android version of ushahidi only to find out that the map on the app is not displaying completely. I saw one of your posts and registered my app with google maps ,obtained the api key and pasted it in the themes.xml of the core folder. However when I run the ushahidi folder, I get an error saying that core.apk was not found and the map still doesn't load properly.Anything I can do ?

Comment: Make sure you've reference the Core project as a library in the Ushahidi folder. You might want to read the BUILDING.txt file.